# Import CSV file using R

Tags: r

I'm trying to import my csv file by using

```
data = read.csv(C:\Users\ldayz\OneDrive\Documents\rating)
```

but I keep getting this error message

> Error: unexpected symbol in "data = read.csv(C:\Users".

I copied the files directory from details so it should be accurate. Am I missing some signs here?

Comment: Try / ou \\ instead of  \

Comment: First of all, you need to provide the function a string, which you didn't include. The \ character in R is called an "escape" character to use for regular expressions. This means that you either have to change to `read.csv("C:\\Users\\ldayz\\OneDrive\\Documents\\rating")` or to change to `read.csv("C:/Users/ldayz/OneDrive/Documents/rating")`.

Comment: when you say string you mean the quotation marks for () right?

I followed instructions by inputting a second \\ and this is the error I'm getting now data = read.csv("C:\\Users\\ldayz\\Linear Algebra\\rating")
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'C:\Users\ldayz\Linear Algebra\rating': No such file or directory
by the way the name of my CSV file is "rating"

Comment: Is the file name "rating" or "rating.csv"? Try `read.csv("C:/Users/ldayz/OneDrive/Documents/rating.csv")`. It that does not work use `dir("C:/Users/ldayz/OneDrive/Documents")` to see if the file is in the directory you are specifying.

Comment: voting to close as it's mostly a typo.

Answer (score 1):

I usually create my Rscript within my directory to avoid having to spell out the location to R.

If you don't have the folder you need pulled up, that's okay. In the window below the global environment, click the three dots in the right corner (red box in the picture).
[image]

Once you've done that, a window will pop up. It'll say "go to folder"
[image]

Find your way to the folder that your file is kept in. When you've found it, click "open". The folder you want/need should now be displayed in the window below the global environment.

To set the folder to your directory, click the settings (the little gear) icon in the window below your global environment. You'll see several options. Click "set as working directory".

[image]

If this works your console should spit out something like this:

```
 setwd("C:/Users/madam_fledershrew/Desktop/ENVS 492")
```

From there you should be able to read in the .csv file using this code:

```
nameofobject=read.csv("name of file.csv", stringsAsFactors = T)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: I notice by creating the Rscript file in my directory for my Jupyter Notebook, it avoided spelling out the location but for this specific issue I cant seen to find where my Rstudio directory is. How can I search to fine where my Rstudio is installed?  I'm very new to these technical process.

Comment: I've added a step by step to guide you through setting your directory. Hope it helps.